# Tesseract IOS performance

Tags: ios, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to do a character recognition on Ipad. I basically want the user to draw characters and digits in real time and the system recognises them. I tried Tesseract with the iOS wrapper found here: https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS But the results are really bad

Picture1:

[image: Picture1]

Picture2:

[image: Picture2]

**The output from picture 1:** LWJ3

**The output from picture 2:** Fnilmling Lu summaryofmajnr news and comments in Ihe Hang Kang Emnomic
Journal. the patent puhlkalinn M EJ Insight, nn Ilnnday. Nwv. ca; TOP

Is it suppose to be like this? Maybe the purpose of libraries such as Tressaract is to recognise photographs of text. But should the performance be this bad? Got any tips how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per what I worked with Tesseract. It is unable to detect handwriting. Tesseract will work with some standard font, most suitable font is **Verdana**. And also before passing image to tesseract do some image filtering.

Answer (score 1):

The first image, with hand-written text, cannot be read by Tesseract.  Furthermore, I tried another top-level high-quality commercial OCR, and even it cannot provide good result from that image.  If you absolutely need to recognize such images, use an ICR capable program.  I have and distribute a commercial application that can read those numbers very well with 100% accuracy, but the cost is premium, used in small-to-medium enterprises environments.

The second image reads very well in a commercial OCR application, and I would expect Tesseract to do better than the result you are showing.  Perhaps producing higher resolution image will help to improve the result.

Ilya Evdokimov

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add filter before processing any image and handling it in tesseract. https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage is a really popular filter for image processing. You can use Luminance filter on it. By the way, you should upload some codes in telling us how you handling your image. I mean in second one as the first one is hand writing. Besides GPUIIMage, i think you can use CIFilter which is also suggested by others to convert black white image.

```
monochromeFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMonochrome" keysAndValues: @"inputColor", [CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0f], @"inputIntensity", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.5f], nil];
```